# JInternalFrame close button displayed half in windows 7

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe

I am adding JInternalframe to JDesktopPane.But JInternalFrame close button in windows 7 is not displayed fully(X).Instead it is displayed half of that "X" symbol.Same code working fine in windows XP.Can anyone please help.

Comment: Seems fine to me.  Can you provide an image?

Comment: Have you used `LayoutManager`s? Done the sizing yourself? or fiddled with `setXXXSize` methods of your JInternalFrame? If its the latter than there's the problem, use layoutmanagers!